# Facebook Javascript SDK persmission issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook JS SDK to log in users to my website. I have a FB button that looks like this:

```
<fb:login-button size="medium" perms="email,publish_stream">Login</fb:login-button>
```

Previously it was working fine but lately it stopped asking for email and publishing permissions. Has smth changed?

Comment: what is the scope u specified on login or in other words for getloginurl() ?

Comment: I don't call getLoginUrl at this stage, I called: $this->facebook->getUser();

Comment: for connecting via FB u must have done some login with facebook and once its successful you are getting /me ? without login u can never get data from FB and more over /me needs access token and its provided after u do login to facebook using the FB connect

Comment: sorry for confusion, I log in using JS SDK. I have permissions defined but it doesn't ask for them (so they are not granted). I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem was that the SDK has changed, not it is "scope" instead of "perms":

```
<fb:login-button size="medium" scope="email,publish_stream">Login</fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the `user_email` permission when asking the users to login? It's a required permission to access the email address. Add it to the `scope` of the login function.

Comment: sorry for confusion, I log in using JS SDK. I have permissions defined but it doesn't ask for them (so they are not granted). I've updated the question